# Movie clips are twitching on Mouse_Over/ Mouse_Out with tweenlite by greensock

Tags: flash, actionscript, gsap

Im using a glow effect as well as a scale effect with tween lite and the scale was working fine until i added the glow. now if i mouse over the wrong way it will cause the movieclip to flicker/twitch between the glowing-scaled and nonglowing-unscaled movieclips.

```
    twitter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, scaleTwitter);
    function scaleTwitter(event: MouseEvent):void {
TweenLite.to(twitter, .1, {scaleX:1.2, scaleY:1.2, ease:Linear.easeNone});
TweenMax.to(twitter, 1, {glowFilter:{color:0xFFFFFF, alpha:1, blurX:30, blurY:30}});
twitter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, unscaleTwitter);

function unscaleTwitter(event: MouseEvent):void {
    TweenLite.to(twitter, .4, {scaleX:1, scaleY:1, ease:Linear.easeNone});
    TweenMax.to(twitter, 1, {glowFilter:{color:0xFFFFFF, alpha:0, blurX:30, blurY:30}});

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

That actually has nothing to do with TweenLite or TweenMax, but rather how Flash handles the hit area when a DisplayObject has a filter (annoying, I know). As far as I know, the only way to handle this is to create another [invisible] DisplayObject that you put on top of your button (or whatever it is) and apply your MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT listeners to that. Obviously still have your tweens control the original object(s). And if you want that hit area to grow/move with the object, you'll need to tween the invisible hit area one too. You could just use a rectangle Sprite with an alpha of 0 for the hit area.

Comment: how can i make an invisible button? if i make a square and then change the alpha to 0 i no longer can click on the object even if i already made it a symbol